# Open iframe manually in nyroModal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, nyromodal

I am trying to get nyroModal to open in an iframe, directly from JavaScript.

To clarify, the following is *not* what I need:

```
$.nmManual(url); // not an iframe
```

because it does not open an iframe.

This will also not work:

```
<a href="http://someurl.com/" target="_blank" class="nyroModal">click me</a>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(".nyroModal").nyroModal(); </script>
```

because I really need to launch it directly from JavaScript.

I've looked through the documentation, and I can't find any obvious way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found a solution:

`$('<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank"></a>').nyroModal(opts).trigger('nyroModal');`

This works, but it's not exactly pretty.  Does anybody know of a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$.nmManual can also be used to open an iframe, using the filters:

```
$.nmManual('http://someurl.com/', {
    callbacks: { 
      initFilters: function(nm) {
      nm.filters.push('link');
      nm.filters.push('iframe');
    }
  }
});
```