# nyroModal v2: How to validate form opened in iframe?

Tags: forms, validation, nyromodal

I'm trying to figure out how to validate a form opened using nyroModal.

The page is being opened as below on click of a button:

```
$(function() {
    $('.btnedit').click(function() {
        $.nmManual('form_page.php);
    });
});
```

On the form that opens up, I have a few fields that are mandatory and a cancel & submit button.

```
<a class="nyroModalClose button" href="#" id="btn_submit">Submit</a>
```

On clicking of the submit button, I want to make sure the mandatory fields have value.  If no, an error message should be displayed & the modal window should not close.

I'm trying to use the jquery validation plugin, but without success.  The modal window always closes irrespective of the validation scripts.

I haven't found much info regarding form validation in a modal window.  Is this not a preferred approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to help you about the jquery validation plugin in a modal window, but I know that using the instruction $.nmManual in that way, the form will not be placed inside the iframe tag, and if I remember correctly the content of new page will be added without header and body tags, so in a word incorrectly. I guess this can produce no validation.

To successfully open an iframe you need to use filters as described here:
[Open iframe manually in nyroModal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183591/open-iframe-manually-in-nyromodal)

I hope this can help you.

Comment: The 'form_page.php' has <head> & <body> tags.  All I want is to populate an input field with a value.  To obtain the value, I open a nyromodal window with a bunch of select options & when the user clicks submit, I want to concatenate the select options values to the input field on the main page.

Comment: If I understand right, even the <iframe> tag is present. In my experience the $.nmManual, if used without filters, opens an iframe if the called page is outside the domain. I didn't understand if if you had already this result or you have been it using the filters, but it doesn't matter.

Anyway, I also used the modal window in a similar way, for selecting copying and pasting. So, because of the iframe, I used cookies to store the id of the input field to populate. I used jquery to performe these operations and close the modal window by clicking of a link rather then a submit button.