# NyroModal v2.0 - Overlay not visible

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

I've been banging my head against the wall with this one for hours.

Currently calling jquery 1.6.4, then loading nyroModal 2.0 (github commit #b12752ee7dcdb1836c2e (09/26/2011))

I'm trying to implement even the most simplest test,

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $.nmManual('http://www.google.com');
    return false; 
});
```

However the overlay is not visible -- the only thing that happens is the background overlay is shown rendering the screen in a black semi-transparent color.

I've messed around in the code using Firebug, and i see that NyroModal container div is being loaded into the page, but it's hidden, and not even being populated with any content.

I've been using nyroModal 1.6 and jquery 1.4.2 for years for with no problems -- but recently needed to upgrade to jquery 1.6.4 -- which means i must upgrade to the latest version of nyroModals..

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open an iframe with nyromodal in "manual" mode.
You can find the right way to do it here:
[Open iframe manually in nyroModal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183591/open-iframe-manually-in-nyromodal/7215662)