# nyroModel does not auto resize

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, nyromodal

Using `$.nmManual` instead of the default `.nyroModal` . The default nyroModel will resize the model automatically based on the browser window size, but the filters are vague at best when trying to set this.

`$('.nyroModal').nyroModal();` Default function works fine.

```
$.nmManual('test.html', {
                        modal: true,              //doesn't seem to do anything  
                               sizes: {
                                      minW: 805,   //this works
                                      minH: 610,
                                      },
                        showCloseButton: false,   //also works
                        anim: { 
                           resize: true,          //both these do nothing
                           showTrans:true,
                        }
```

I nyromodel site makes it quite hard to understand exactly what parameters the `resize`, `def`, and `showtrans` actually use.

Comment: I'm reading right now your question... you have solved your issue? If not, could you explain better what you're looking for?

Comment: Using `$.nmManual` does not include the defualt functionality of `.nyroModal()` so for example the auto-resize (to browser size) does not work and the documentation is very poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some answers about using the plugin in manual mode through `$.nmManual`.
Basically you have to init filters with a code like this:

```
$.nmManual('http://mypage.html/', {
    callbacks: { 
      initFilters: function(nm) {
      nm.filters.push('somefilter');
      nm.filters.push('anotherfilter');
    }
  }
});
```

To open manually a page just you need `$.nmManual('mypage.html');` if I remember right it will load the `link` filter, but if you want open manually a page inside an iframe you need both `link` and `iframe` filter: [Open iframe manually in nyroModal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183591/open-iframe-manually-in-nyromodal/7215662)

About resizing of a loaded page, time ago I was dealing with but I have no results... using this code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($.nmTop() !== undefined)
    {
        $.nmTop().resize(true);
    }
});
```

we can force resizing but in this case it works very bad, with a delay step as you can see playing with the window... I had no more time to rewrite `resize` function...

I don't know if this behaviour is the same with using a DOM selector.

Finally the option `modal: true` prevents closing of the popup window when you click outside its edge,  that is in the dark background.

Comment: Thank you, I also was forcing a resize and it was not very good compared to the default, I ended up just doing it with css, I will leave the question open for a bit in case anyone else knows.