# How to auto resize nyro modal

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

I using Nyromodal v2. I load Iframe url with:

```
    $.nmManual('http://mypage.html/', {
    callbacks: { 
      initFilters: function(nm) {
      nm.filters.push('somefilter');
      nm.filters.push('anotherfilter');
    }
  }
});
```

It work fine...but I want nyromodal window auto resize with iframe size. I'm try [nyroModel does not auto resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263548/nyromodel-does-not-auto-resize)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($.nmTop() !== undefined)
    {
        $.nmTop().resize(true);
    }
});
```

but it not resize...pls guide me...

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console.

Comment: I don't get any thing....with $(window).resize function

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready)

```
$(function(){// so that your plugin
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if($.nmTop() !== undefined)
    {
        $.nmTop().resize(true);
    }
  });
});
```