# using nyroModal, want iframe to automatically load upon page load

Tags: iframe, onload, nyromodal

Saw alot of manual loads of iframes in answers, but I need the page to automatically load the fist menu option and I am using nyroModal (class=iframe which opens it iframe style with nyroModal).

The reason for this is the menu for a bunch of other iframe content is in this iframe as well and I'd like it to stay open and the menu stay in this auto opened iframe.

Hopefully this makes sense to someone.(?)

Comment: Could you explain better your needs?

Comment: automatic iframe opening upon page load, using nyromodal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the manual function inside the event handling:

```
$(window).load(function() {
      // my code to open manually an iframe using nyroModal
});
```

You can get the snippet to open the iframe at this page: [Open iframe manually in nyroModal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183591/open-iframe-manually-in-nyromodal)